# when I want to insert a value into sqlite table my app keep crashing when I add quotation mark in editText How to fix this?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

please help me I dont know how to fix this error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'''" (code 1): , while compiling: select * from Repository where itemName = '''
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

here is the codes  that causing the error the input activity & database hapler

```
 final String query = "select * from Repository where itemName = '" + name + "'";
            if (mDataBase.getData(query).getCount() > 0) {....}
```

and the code in dbhalper

```
public Cursor getData(String sql) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `name` in your Java code?  You should read about using prepared statements with SQLite (and a Google search on this should turn up a lot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that name contains the value **'** this requires special handling and needs to be **''** as per :-

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes
>   ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two
>   single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the
>   backslash character are not supported because they are not standard
>   SQL.
>   [expression - Literal Values (Constants)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

I believe that if you used (if no arguments then pass null) :-

```
public Cursor getData(String sql, String[] args) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    return database.rawQuery(sql, args);
}
```

Along with :-

```
final String query = "select * from Repository where itemName =?";
if (mDataBase.getData(query,new String[]{name}).getCount() > 0) {....}
```

That the **?** will be replaced with the correct value.